# What are the names by which runways are classified according to the configuration of the placement of the approach lighting systems?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airport-lighting, jeppesen, symbology

What are the names by which runways are classified according to the configuration of the placement of the approach lighting systems? (I'm not talking about HIALS or HIALS-II because those terms are used for so many configurations)
[image]

Comment: In the Airport diagram, we see that the approach light systems for the two runways are represented by different symbols. The reason why these symbols are different is that the placement and configurations of the lighting systems are different. So what are the names of these different configurations? That's what I was asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the reference material for US airports.  I suspect from your airport diagram that you may not be referring to US:

#### Figure from the US AIM (Aeronautical Information Manual), located [online here.](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_1.html)

[image: Figure from the US AIM]

#### Figure from the FAA Digital Terminal Procedures Supplemental

[image]

#### From the Chart Supplement Legend

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to ask that to be sure about it, ALSF is the equivalent of HIALS and ALSF-II is the equivalent of HIALS-II? Am I right about that?

Comment: In the US I haven't seen a reference to "HAILS-II" so I am not sure.  The FAA breaks approach lighting systems in "High Intensity Approach Lighting Systems" and "Medium Intensity Approach Lighting Systems."  ALSF-2, ALSF-1, SSALR, SALS and SALSR are all considered "High Intensity" systems.  MALS, MALSF, MALSR, SSALS, and SSALF are all medium intensity.

Comment: The ICAO system in Europe is trying to copy from the US FAA, but unfortunately many things are missing. Thank you very much for your answers.